# How can i use multiple table in select query?(without Inner join)

Tags: php, mysql, select, search

I want to get two tables in one select query without inner join can i do that?

```
if(isset($_POST['search']))    
{   $name=$_POST['searchtxt'];    

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `product_tb_men` WHERE `name` LIKE '%".$name."%'");    

}
```

this is not the complete code and the second table name is product_tb_women..

Comment: Well there are other options as well instead of `inner join` like `left join, right join`

Comment: without inner join, you can try UNION to select distinct records between two tables.

Comment: See SQL injection and PHP's deprecated mysql_ API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNION` this way

```
if(isset($_POST['search']))    
{
    $name=$_POST['searchtxt'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `product_tb_men` WHERE `name` LIKE '%".$name."%'"
                ." UNION "
                ."SELECT * FROM `product_tb_women` WHERE `name` LIKE '%".$name."%'";

    $result = mysql_query($query);
}
```

You do need to consider the usage of `mysql_*` functions and sanitize the value of name to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Fixed, please try now.

Answer (score 0):

Use if statement...  If(first query) {do } else if (second query ) {do}

Answer (score 0):

$result = mysql_query("SELECT *.pm, *.pw 
FROM `product_tb_men` pm,  product_tb_women pw WHERE `pm.name` LIKE '%".$name."%'" or pw.name LIKE '%".$name."%'");